# Asp.net mvc 5 identity smtp connection

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, smtp, asp.net-identity

I search all way for use forgot passwrod on (youtube,docMicrosoft..) with no result  . Please someone explain me the error and expose part by part the process forgotpassword from webconfig to identityConfig service . Thanks 
this is the **error :**

### Le serveur SMTP requiert une connexion sécurisée ou le client n'était pas authentifié. La réponse du serveur était : 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

this is  methode of **controller :**

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                // Ne révélez pas que l'utilisateur n'existe pas ou qu'il n'est pas confirmé
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            // Pour plus d'informations sur l'activation de la confirmation de compte et de la réinitialisation de mot de passe, visitez https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Envoyer un message électronique avec ce lien
            string Code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code= Code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Réinitialiser le mot de passe", "Réinitialisez votre mot de passe en cliquant <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">ici</a>");
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
```

And this is my methode IndentyConfig :

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{


    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {


        // Credentials:
        var credentialUserName = "morad21838@gmail.com";
        var sentFrom = "morad21838@gmail.com";
        var pwd = "95147823";

        // Configure the client:
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client =
            new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        // Creatte the credentials:
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential(credentialUserName, pwd);

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        // Create the message:
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(sentFrom, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;

        // Send:
        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);

    }
}
```

And this is my **web.config :**

> ```
>   </appSetting>
>   <system.net>
>     <mailSettings>
>       <smtp from="haniyac1@gmail.com">
>         <network host="smtp-relay.gmail.com"
>                  port="587"
>                  userName="haniyac1@gmail.com"
>                  password="95147823" />
>       </smtp>
>     </mailSettings>
>   </system.net>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I find solution and is work perfectly wish that help someone have the same error .

this is updated file :

**IdentityConfig**

```
   public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {


        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            return client.SendMailAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["toEmail"],
                                        message.Destination,
                                        message.Subject,
                                        message.Body);
        }
    }
```

**Web.Config**

> ```
> <!--Smptp Server (confirmations emails)-->
> <add key="toEmail" value="haniyac1@gmail.com" />
> <add key="UserId" value="haniyac1@gmail.com" />
> <add key="Password" value="95147823" />
> <add key="SMTPPort" value="587" />
> <add key="Host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
> ```

```
>   </appSettings>  
> <appSettings>
>  <system.net>
>     <mailSettings>
>       <smtp from="morad28138@gmail.com">
>         <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="morad28138" defaultCredentials="false" password="95147823" port="587"
> enableSsl="true" />
>       </smtp>
>     </mailSettings>
```

Controller **forgotPassword Method :**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                // Ne révélez pas que l'utilisateur n'existe pas ou qu'il n'est pas confirmé
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            // Pour plus d'informations sur l'activation de la confirmation de compte et de la réinitialisation de mot de passe, visitez https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Envoyer un message électronique avec ce lien
            string Code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code= Code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Réinitialiser le mot de passe", "Réinitialisez votre mot de passe en cliquant <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">ici</a>");
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        // Si nous sommes arrivés là, un échec s’est produit. Réafficher le formulaire
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Register : post**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // Pour plus d'informations sur l'activation de la confirmation de compte et de la réinitialisation de mot de passe, visitez https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Envoyer un message électronique avec ce lien
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrll = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, Code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmez votre compte", "Confirmez votre compte en cliquant <a href=\"" + callbackUrll + "\">ici</a>");

                string callbackUrl = await SendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account");

                //await this.UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, model.Roles);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles.Where(a => !a.Name.Contains("Admins")), "Name", "Name");
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // Si nous sommes arrivés là, un échec s’est produit. Réafficher le formulaire
        return View(model);
    }
```

Hope that help